# How to target iOS devices lower than a specific OS using @available

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that is aimed at iOS 11+ marked with the following:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
```

Now I need to target a different function for iOS versions less than iOS 11. How do I write that?

Comment: Add an `else` to your `if`.

Comment: @rmaddy I can't, it's a delegate function provided by apple

Comment: Show more code in your question. Clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: If it is a delegate function, the I doubt there is any alternate for lower versions of iOS, since lower versions won't call that delegate method. You need to provide more information in your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {} else {
    // do something (pre iOS 11.0)
}
```

Comment: Swift 5.6 introduced the #unavailable attribute as well.